# segmentation fault with pjsip binary on android device

Tags: android, pjsip

I want to run pjsip on android device through adb shell.

For this i have compiled the pjsip binary for android.I am following the
below link.
https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android#pjsua2

Here are some of the specifications i am using while compiling the pjsip.
    Target_ABI= armeabi-v7a
    API Level = android-19
    Android version on device = KITKAT
    NDK version = r10e

Android Device Details:
    ARCH = Arm 32 bit
    OS = Android(KITKAT)
    TARGET = armeabi,armeabi-v7

When i check the binary compiled with above parameteres with file command
it shows.

pjsua-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, ARM,
EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs),not stripped.

Now i push binary so created to /system/bin and all the .so and .a files
to /system/lib on android device using adb push command.

Now when i run
the binary on adb shell ,I am getting SEGMENTATION FAULT.

Now my question   are:
    1. What  can be the possible reasons of this SEGMENTATION FAULT?
    2. Do i need to push all the .so ,.a ,.h files on android devics.If
    yes,then at what  path?
    3. I have tried all the ndk versions(9b,9d,10e,11b,11c) but getting
    same issue.So is there any kind of platform dependency issue.I
    mean the toolchain in ndk is of 64 bit arch but android device is
    of 32 bit arch.

Kindly let me know if there are any workaround details for the above issue.

Comment: Now i am using remote gdb debugging by running gdbserver on android device and ndk's gdb on linux system but getting this error:

Cannot access memory at address 0x0.

Any Idea for this?